# some strange android error

Tags: android, opencv

https://github.com/mustafaakin/image-matcher

I imported this project using AndroidStudio's "Import Eclipse Studio Project". Edited .properties 'OpenCV - x.x.x' to 'opencv'. This is the error:

```
/home/uttaran/Downloads/h1/h/src/main/res/layout/main_layout.xml
Error:(62) No resource identifier found for attribute 'camera_id' in package 'in.mustafaak.imagematcher'
Error:(62) No resource identifier found for attribute 'show_fps' in package 'in.mustafaak.imagematcher'
Error:Execution failed for task ':h:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/home/uttaran/Android/Sdk/build-tools/23.0.3/aapt'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Information:BUILD FAILED
```

Comment: Please write down the code and errors with proper formatting, and remove the image

Comment: Does the project have build.gradle files? Because I don't see any.

Answer (score 1):

As Daniel K already stated correctly:

To important an Android Application/Library in Android Studio, the project you want to import needs a **build.gradle** or **pom.xml** file in the root of the project so that the build system (Gradle/Maven) that comes with Android Studio can resolve dependencies etc. during the project import...

The Github project you refering too is this?
https://github.com/mustafaakin/image-matcher
Apparently it got written with the Eclipse IDE...and pushed to Github without any build file...

You can import it anyway, by manually creating a **build.gradle** file in the project root and then try to import the application again.

A possible working build.gradle file (depends on your Android Studio's Gradle plugin Version etc. I just assume now you copied your build.gradle file from a working project of yours) would be:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
}
```

If you did this, it probably will not find the OpenCV library dependency (red lines under OpenCV classes/methods and in imports) and you have to go in Android Studio to: 
File | Project Structure | image-matcher-master | Dependencies | +

And there you add your OpenCV library as "File dependency"...if it is a JAR...otherwise if opencv in your Download folder is the source...you load this in Android Studio as well and choose "Module dependency".

If this doesn't work...this could be helpful as well:
http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html

**UPDATE:**

main_layout.xml contains things like:

```
<org.opencv.android.NativeCameraView
            android:id="@+id/tutorial1_activity_native_surface_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:onClick="cameraclick"
            android:visibility="gone"
            opencv:camera_id="any"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            opencv:show_fps="true" />
```

So your OpenCV library comes with resources and views that can't be found, so you still have some problem with your src structure in your project.
This answer might be related:
[Android Studio can't find opencv modules, but compiles ok](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24331393/android-studio-cant-find-opencv-modules-but-compiles-ok)

If nothing works I would recommend to import an OpenCV Android sample, check if it builds and compiles and then compare the src structure difference from your project to the sample project...

[Open the Android native Camera using OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17165777/open-the-android-native-camera-using-opencv)

Comment: Thanks!helped a lot.